# Kusto summarize total count from different rows

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

The count from the below data table for the same build, device, and Tier is split into different rows because the os versions are different. How do I summarize the total, excluding the platform os, please? For example , I need to summarize the total count as 1388+1739+2070 for build - "19.50.20",device - "Google",Tier - 3

```
datatable (build_ver: string, device: string, Tier: long, count: long, os: string) 
[
 
    "19.50.20","Google",long(3),long(1388),"10.1",
    "19.50.20","Google",long(3),long(1739),"10.2",
    "19.50.20","Google",long(3),long(2070),"10.3",
    "19.50.20","Windows",long(2),long(1486),"11",
    "19.50.20","Windows",long(2),long(1476),"11.2",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this could work:

```
datatable (build_ver: string, device : string, tier: long, count: long, os: string)
[
"19.50.20","Google",long(3),long(1388),"10.1", 
"19.50.20","Google",long(3),long(1739),"10.2",
"19.50.20","Google",long(3),long(2070),"10.3",
"19.50.20","Windows",long(2),long(1486),"11",
"19.50.20","Windows",long(2),long(1476),"11.2", 
]
| summarize sum(count) by build_ver, device, tier
```